# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyecharts'

Tags: python

I do not understand while running the example code from pyecharts, it is still giving me module not found error.

ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
----> 1 from pyecharts.charts import Bar
2 from pyecharts import options as opts
3
4 bar = (
5     Bar()

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyecharts'

Comment: Have you installed 'pyecharts'? If so have you tried to search for the module? E.g. with `pip search pyecharts`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have activated the virtual environment. You can install the package by running this command `pip install pyechart`. You should freeze the package into the requirements.txt file by running this command `pip freeze -r requirements.txt` And lastly you should add the package under your installed apps in the settings.py file, if any command exists for that. You could read the full documentation here https://pyecharts.readthedocs.io/en/latest/en-us/documentation/ to clear any further doubts.

Answer (score 1):

try do this steps:

1. Check that you have installed module in right envy (`pip list`).
2. If you don't have, install by using pip (`pip install pyecharts -U`). see doc https://github.com/pyecharts/pyecharts/
3. If you have this library, try restart you kernel (if you using Jupyter) and reinstall library again

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried to install missing library?
https://pypi.org/project/pyecharts/

```
pip install pyecharts
```

You can verify if library is in place by this command:

```
pip freeze
```